# Show that For $A$ closed in a metric space $(,)$ and $a$ isn't in A, $(,A):=inf[(a,x) : x \in A]$ > 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

I understand the problem. Since a isn't on A, then the distance between a to closest point of A to x will be larger than zero because there will always be some distance between them and that point will always be on the closure of A, but I don't know how I can show this in Analysis terms. Can you show me some ways please?  Thank you in advance.

Can I just say:

Let $a\in X, a \notin A$ and $y \in A$. Then $\forall y \in A$ , $dist(a,x)>0 \implies inf[(a,x)| x \in A] > 0$

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking to prove. By the way, what you wrote is not correct: what if $A$ is open?

Comment: What's your definition of distance between a point and a set? Because for me, what you wrote is the definition. How else define it?

Comment: The way you pose your question, there is nothing to answer, you define $d(x,A) := \dots$. What should it really be? Also, your argument is not quite right, $a \not \in A$ does not suffice to have $d(x, A) > 0$. Closedness is essential.

Comment: Btw, the statement below is false. There are sets which don't contain their infimum.

Comment: I forgot to add ">0" on the question, ops sorry. Now, if I add the closedness property of A to my proof, would it be correct?

Comment: No. You need to explain how to use it! I will post a personal hint as an answer.

Comment: You need to answer the question! What is the **definition** of $d(x,A)$?

Comment: Distance between x and every element of A? I don't understand why my proof doesn't show that, since x isn't in A and A is closed, every distance between every element of A and x is obviously bigger than 0 which is also means smallest distance between x and elements of A is bigger than zero since none of them are not equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $d(A, a) =0$.
By definition of the infimum, there's an element $x_n\in A$ such that $d(x_n, a) <1/n$ for every positive integer $n$. 
But then $x_n\to a$ follows, and if $A$ is closed, it implies $a\in A$.